# Textbooks for mathematical/computing/physics teaching that are based on empirical research

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy

I am looking for any (and all) books (on math, physics and Computer Science) that discuss how to teach and selects methods based on empirical research and solid evidence. My biggest interest right now is on the second half of primary education and secondary education.

I'd prefer books that constrast different approaches and ponder their effectiveness empirically, rather than books that propose one particular approach.

(I teach at an NGO, and have interest in teaching, but my formal education is in Computer Science. I am trying to approach the field with as much a evidence-based approach as possible)

---

I know that (math and physics and CS) is broad. My reason for asking is that I'd like to have as many examples as possible, so that I can better understand the what empirical approaches to STEM education exist, and choose which approaches to further study.

Comment: "any (and all) books (on math, physics and Computer Science) that discuss how to teach" is, I think, too broad... even with the constraint that it be evidence-based and geared toward middle/high school. Maybe it would be better to pose this question in some small area first?

Comment: Based on the question title I was going to suggest this (researched suggestions on uni maths teaching): http://homepages.lboro.ac.uk/~malja/Home_files/Alcock_Simpson_book.pdf
It doesn't really answer the question asked, but might be of use to others who are looking here.

Comment: Based on "I know that (math and physics and CS) is too broad" I have, indeed, voted to close as *Too Broad*.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman, my reason to ask for such a broad variety is that I am trying to get a bird's eye view of empirical research in STEM education.
Thanks for your comments. I do not mean to ignore them, but hope the question is still aceptable

Answer (score 2):

For physics, I've found the following helpful:

Mazur, Peer Instruction: A User's Manual

Arons, Teaching Introductory Physics

The Mazur book is really the evidence-based book you're looking for. Unfortunately it's out of date. You can absorb the general pedagogical research results without necessarily using exactly Mazur's method of teaching. Basically the research supports active engagement rather than lecturing.